# PHP Script is still getting executed even with isset( ) submit button check after browser refresh

Tags: php, forms, submit, isset

I am self studying newbie to PHP.
I would like to run a small PHP script only if the submit button is clicked. Unfortunately the function `isset()` that (according to my tutorial lesson) performs this submit button check -does not seem to be working !

When I refresh the page in the browser, part of the PHP script: `print("You're not a member of this site");` is still getting executed even though I have not yet pressed the submit button! Why?

and the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>

    <?PHP
        if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];

            if ($username == "letmein") {

                print ("Welcome back, friend!");

            }
            else {

                print ("You're not a member of this site");

            }
        }
    ?>
</head>
    <body>
        <Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="basicForm.php">
            <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="username" NAME="username">
<p>

            <Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Login">
        </FORM>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: html should be in all lowercase, but shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Did you get a message stating the data of the request would be send again?

Comment: I just tried this on my local server and it works perfectly. Are you entering in "letmein" as the username?

Comment: Are you using browsers refresh or F5 key or what?

Comment: please try by clearing browser chache!

Comment: What @PeeHaa implies is that if you hit "Refresh" button some browsers will repeat last request: be it GET or POST. Does your page "missbehave" if you put the cursor into address bar and hit Enter?

Comment: @sandip I am using Chrome - where is the browser Chache setting? - surely you should not need to clear browser cache every time.

Comment: @Mr_leighman use short cut key ctrl+shift+del

Comment: @Yakimets Yes that works o.k: putting  the cursor in the address bar and hitting 'Enter' does stop the PHP code from getting executed. but is still not ideal, as this surely should not be necassary with  browsers.

Comment: I am using browser refresh

Comment: @PeeHaa No I did not get message: 'stating the data of the request would be send again'

Comment: @ Michael Ozeryansky it does not matter if you enter 'letmein' or not, point is: Any part the PHP code within the if(isset()){} should not get executed with browser refresh.

Comment: see @techie_28 's answer. There is no workaround for your current code.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using browser's refresh or the `F5` key you need to redirect immediately after submission and it wont surpass isset on refreshing.

Like after `mysql_query` function which you have written for INSERT record on form submission you need to write a

> header('Location:yourpage.php')

And it will prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by 'redirect immediately' please

Comment: You can save some data into session, set some cookie - and do `Header("Location: basicForm.php")`; And implement some $_COOKIE check - and `print ("Welcome back, friend!")` then.

Comment: @ Max Yakimets O.K Thanks. Not sure how to do what you just said but I will play with it and get back to you all with result

Comment: Cleared the browser cache. Php code is still getting executed

Answer (score 0):

instead of isset()

**USE**

!empty($_POST)

Comment: This shouldn't matter for OPs problem.

Comment: @Manish GoyalTried Tried this, works o.k, but there is still no change in the result (PHP code still gets executed after browser refresh). How am I supposed to reference 'submit1' with this piece of code anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

Im also new to php, will just share my experience..
I have 2 visions of this.. 1st is if you have many forms, you need to add the form="form1" attrtibute insde inputs and buttons to have a single form for the $_POST.

second thought is..

without ajax, 
the $_POST method sends the data on click but the request from the server comes after refresh only. Meaning the data shown from the post is 1 refresh behind.

You can add a hidden radio or check button with some "check value" like "1"..
untill this button receives a value, you can then compare the value, if its true, then you show one message, if not, then another.

But you need a default value, either an empty one or it will always start from "you are not a member" untill the checkbox changes value.

```
<?php
 $username = "";
 $username = (isset($_POST['Submit1']) ? $_POST['Submit1'] : "");
?>
<Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="basicForm.php">
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="username" NAME="username">

<INPUT hidden TYPE = "checkbox" NAME="check_trigger"
<?php if(!is_empty($username)){ echo "checked";}; ?> >

<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Login">
</FORM>
```

so when the username is entered, the checkbox gets autochecked, and you can 
echo the greeting message even if the name is changed...
am i out of topic..

or you can put your name as default inside isset

```
$username = (isset($_POST['Submit1']) ? $_POST['Submit1'] : "letmein");
```

and have

```
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" 
VALUE =<?php"echo htmlspecialchars($username);?>" NAME="username">
```

but you need some validation and security for it.